# Show combobox item dynamically, depending on the record

Tags: c#, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

I want to display a Comboxbox Item, depending on a data table.
for example:

1 = open
2 = close
....

The combobox content is created with the datatable:

string sqlStr = "select **id**, **description** from sdg.pa_status";

```
        MySqlDataAdapter adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlStr, conn);

        adapt.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapt.Fill(ds);

        **_status** = ds.Tables[0];
```

combox is created:

```
            column.Name = "status";
            column.DropDownWidth = 160;
            column.Width = 160;
            column.FlatStyle = 0;
            column.HeaderText = "Status";

            column.DataSource = **_status**;
            column.DataPropertyName = dGVQuote.Columns["**stat**"].ToString(); 
            column.ValueMember = _status.Columns[1].ToString();
            column.DisplayMember = _status.Columns[1].ToString();
```

datagrid is generated:

```
    private void CustomizeDataGridViewOrder()
    {
        dGVQuote.DataSource = GetQuote("");

        dGVQuote.Columns["ID"].Width = 135;
        dGVQuote.Columns["ID"].HeaderText = "Angebotsnummer";
        dGVQuote.Columns["idorder"].Visible = false;
        dGVQuote.Columns["Description"].Width = 225;
        dGVQuote.Columns["Description"].HeaderText = "Beschreibung";
        dGVQuote.Columns["comment"].Width = 225;
        dGVQuote.Columns["comment"].HeaderText = "interner Kommentar";
        dGVQuote.Columns["idcust"].Visible = false;
        dGVQuote.Columns["idobj"].Visible = false;
        dGVQuote.Columns["cnt"].Width = 60;
        dGVQuote.Columns["cnt"].HeaderText = "Anzahl MA";
        dGVQuote.Columns["**stat**"].Visible = true;
        dGVQuote.Columns.Add(CreateComboBoxColumn());
        dGVQuote.Columns["valid"].Width = 135;
        dGVQuote.Columns["valid"].HeaderText = "gültig bis";

        dGVQuote.DataSource = GetQuote(""); //datatable is handed over
```

I am desperate. Can someone help me?